# formula to know when 3 sine waves with different frequencies reach first point together again?

Tags: frequency

I'm looking for formula if any or shortcut math, for following problem.
Let's say we have 3 sine waves with frequency 100, 70, 20. Assuming all 3 start on point-0, each wave cycles based on it's own frequency, but when do these 3 waves together reach point-0 as in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time periods of the three waves are $\frac{1}{100},\frac{1}{70}, \frac{1}{20}$. At any integer multiple of this time period, a wave will be back at point $0$. So, you basically want the lcm of these periods, i.e. the time when all of them simultaneously reach point $0$, which you can easily find to be $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: corollary: If one or more of the periods are irrational,  there will never be a time when all three meet.

Comment: @garyp Not the periods, but any of their ratios. For example, periods pi & 2pi do meet despite being irrational.